# Customize which TableRows appear on which page using TablePagination (Material-ui)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to be able to set whatever table row I want to a specific page. For example, If I have three TableRows and want the first two on page one in my DataTable and the third one on page two. I'm new to programming so the more thorough the explanation the better. Here is a quick peek at my code.

I have the rows in the TableBody inside the TableContainer:

```
 <TableRow className="property_taxes" hover>
          <TableCell>Property Taxes</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow className="maintenance" hover>
          <TableCell>Maintenance</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow className="total_costs" hover>
          <TableCell>Total</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
```

And then I have the TablePagination right after that:

```
  <TablePagination
      component="div"
      count={7}
      rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
      rowsPerPageOptions={[]}
      page={page}
      onChangePage={handleChangePage}
    />
```

Thank you in advance!

```
export default function DataTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <TableContainer component={Paper} className={classes.container}>
        <Table stickyHeader className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Expenses</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Monthly&nbsp;($)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Yearly&nbsp;($)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Total&nbsp;($)</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody className={classes.tableBody}>
            <TableRow className="principle" hover>
              <TableCell id="name">Principle</TableCell>
              <TableCell id="monthly"align="right">0</TableCell>
              <TableCell id="yearly"align="right">0</TableCell>
              <TableCell id="total"align="right">0</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow className="private_mortgage_insurance" hover>
              <TableCell>Private Mortgage Insurance</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow className="interest" hover>
              <TableCell>Interest</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow className="property_taxes" hover>
              <TableCell>Property Taxes</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow className="maintenance" hover>
              <TableCell>Maintenance</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow className="total_costs" hover>
              <TableCell>Total</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow className="closing_costs" hover>
              <TableCell>Closing Costs</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">0</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      <TablePagination
          component="div"
          count={7}
          rowsPerPage={6}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[]}
          page={page}
          onChangePage={handleChangePage}
        />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah so I have multiple different pages or sections whatever you want to call them in a single DataTable which you can navigate with Pagination. Exactly, I want Row_1 and Row_2 on one page and Row_3 on another. Is there something like page={1} I can put inside my TableRows?

Comment: How would I do that? I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to javascript, react, and material-ui.

Comment: You didn't make the content reactive, refer the demo in the official document and make the adjustment of `<TableBody />`would be good

Comment: I don't understand